# Incorrect sql generated by jooq on rare occasions

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, kotlin, jooq, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a spring cloud gateway application saving authentication data to db. Application runs in kubernetes. I have too different cases, sometimes I have json data to save and other times json data is null. Code to save this data looks like this:

```
    with(AUTHENTICATED_SESSION) {
        context.insertInto(this, ACCESS_TOKEN_MD5_HASH, REFRESH_TOKEN, CONTEXT_DATA)
            .values(
                accessTokenMd5,
                refreshToken,
                if (contextData != null) {
                    JSONB.jsonb(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(contextData))
                } else {
                    null
                }
            )
            .execute()
    }
```

Generated column definition

```
public final TableField<AuthenticatedSessionRecord, JSONB> CONTEXT_DATA = createField(DSL.name("context_data"), SQLDataType.JSONB, this, "");
```

Saving null value usually works like it should be:

```
insert into "public"."authenticated_session" ("access_token_md5_hash", "refresh_token", "context_data") values (?, ?, cast(? as jsonb))
    : -> with bind values      : insert into "public"."authenticated_session" ("access_token_md5_hash", "refresh_token", "context_data") values ('hash', 'token', cast(null as jsonb))
```

Sometimes query looks like this and it causes exception below

```
insert into "public"."authenticated_session" ("access_token_md5_hash", "refresh_token", "context_data") values (?, ?, ?)
    : -> with bind values      : insert into "public"."authenticated_session" ("access_token_md5_hash", "refresh_token", "context_data") values ('hash', 'token', null)
```

```
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [insert into "public"."authenticated_session" ("access_token_md5_hash", "refresh_token", "context_data") values (?, ?, ?)]; ERROR: column "context_data" is of type jsonb but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 121
    at org.jooq_3.14.6.DEFAULT.debug(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.translate(Tools.java:2880) ~[jooq-3.14.6.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.sqlException(DefaultExecuteContext.java:757) ~[jooq-3.14.6.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:389) ~[jooq-3.14.6.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractDelegatingQuery.execute(AbstractDelegatingQuery.java:119) ~[jooq-3.14.6.jar:na]
```

So it seems that on rare occasions jooq generates incorrect sql (without cast to jsonb).

The problem is really annoying as application is not usable at all when this happens. Restarting the pod helps. Most likely this problem appears only after application is started.

Used versions:

- jooq 3.14.6
- spring boot 2.3.5.RELEASE
- spring cloud gateway 2.2.5.RELEASE
- Postgresql 10.12 in docker container
- postgresql driver 42.2.5
- kotlin 1.4.10

Comment: Unrelated: Please upgrade to at least 3.14.7 because of a memory leak in 3.14.5 - 3.14.6: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11353

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a hint in your question, and every time I see it, I'm very happy to have implemented this feature:

```
 at org.jooq_3.14.6.DEFAULT.debug(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

`DEFAULT` refers to [`SQLDialect.DEFAULT`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/SQLDialect.html#DEFAULT), but it should be [`SQLDialect.POSTGRES`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/SQLDialect.html#POSTGRES) in your case. The reason why you're getting invalid SQL is because in those cases, you don't have a correctly configured `Configuration`.

That should help you track down the problem, keeping in mind that jOOQ `Query` objects aren't thread safe.

Comment: Nice, could you hyperlink location in source code where you generate them? Thx

Comment: @bedla.czech: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/a90999b2dada1c0c07dd939244814a1266f87171/jOOQ/src/main/java/org/jooq/impl/DefaultExecuteContext.java#L667-L685

Comment: Yes, this is really the reason. Without configuring dialect spring boot tries to determine with the connection (and have failed in these rare occassions):

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jooq/SqlDialectLookup.java

Comment: @Mikke: Oh interesting. Do you think there's a bug in that discovery? Why doesn't it work some times? Of course, an explicit dialect is always better, but it might be convenient to omit it...

Comment: @LukasEder I have no reason to believe there is a bug in discovery. I guess that my problem is because of our dev environment. CI publishes new images and deploys them to kubernetes. Rarely db container hasn't started before application and causes discovery to fail. Luckily this shouldn't happen in production where db is not in kubernetes pod.