# Can't set a nonstring value to null in database with jooq UpdateQuery in Kotlin

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, jooq

(It's similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66870048/incorrect-sql-generated-by-jooq-on-rare-occasions), but this time it knows it's POSTGRES.)

I have an UpdateQuery:

```
      val uq = kontxt.updateQuery(table("felhaszn"))
      uq.addValue(field("kilepett"), null as Timestamp?
```

and it generates (`println(uq.getSQL())`):

```
update felhaszn set /*...*/ kilepett = cast(? as varchar) /*...*/
```

Why varchar?
At `uq.execute()` it throws an

```
ERROR: column "kilepett" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type character varying
```

While the output of `println(uq.toString())` shows the correct SQL. So I could work around it by `kontxt.query(uq.toString()).execute()` rather than just `uq.execute()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wouldn't happen if you would be using the [code generator](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/), in case of which you'd have type information attached to your columns, and jOOQ could bind the correct type:

```kotlin
val uq = kontxt.updateQuery(FELHASZN)
uq.addValue(FELHASZN.KILEPETT, null as Timestamp?)
```

Your cast to `Timestamp?` doesn't help here, because that type information isn't maintained by the JVM at runtime. The `null` reference has no type, and your `field("kilepett")` doesn't have any type information attached to it, either (it's a `Field<Object?>`). If for some reason you cannot use the code generator (I highly recommend you do!), you'll have to attach this information explicitly:

```kotlin
uq.addValue(field("kilepett", SQLDataType.TIMESTAMP), null as Timestamp?)
```